# How to reduce the gap between a figure and enumerate environment

Tags: spacing, floats

I'd like to reduce the blank space between a figure that I generate via `tikz` and `enumaration` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}[nosep]
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
       thick,acteur/.style={ circle,fill=black,thick,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=0.3cm
       },font = \scriptsize
     ]
        \node (0) at (0,0) [acteur]{};
        \node (1) at (1,-2) [acteur]{};
        \node (2) at (2,0) [acteur]{};
         \foreach \from/\to in {0/1, 0/2, 1/2} \draw[thick](\from) -- (\to); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I have updated all `displayskip`s, however, there seems like a redundant space.  In the original document, it looks quite bizarre.

[image]

Comment: Most likely unrelated but a `\label`without a `\caption` does not really make sense. Did you remove the `\caption` for the MWE or is there no caption in your actual document?

Comment: I did remove everything to create a MWE. Otherwise, I do have all the information in the original text file. I have edited my post and removed ```\label```.

Comment: the displayskips are for display math so have would no effect here even if you ran the `\zerodisplayskips` command (which this example does not do).  the enumerate is in the main document flow but you have specified that the tikz is in a float so is taken out of the flow and is an insert that may be inserted to help with page breaking, so there isn't really a define space between these things,  but perhaps you are looking for `\intextsep` which is the space added if the float is positioned using `h`

Comment: If you always want the tikzpicture to be above the enumerate simply omit the `figure` environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great! ```\setlength{\intextsep}{0mm}``` actually has solved my problem. If you share this as an answer, I can go ahead and accept it.

Comment: There is also a gap at the top of every list, which can include \topsep, \partopsep and/or \parskip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The displayskips are for display math so have would no effect here even if you ran the `\zerodisplayskips` command (which this example does not do). the enumerate is in the main document flow but you have specified that the tikz is in a float so is taken out of the flow and is an insert that may be inserted to help with page breaking, so there isn't really a definite space between these things.

A float which is positioned by `h` will have `\intextsep` spacing added above and below so you could reduce that, however if you always want the tikz to be above the enumerate then you should not float it, and simply remove the `figure` environment.